# How to hide GUI of any Windows program?

Tags: windows, window-manager

I want to leave a program running in the background without its windows from popping up despite the fact that the program is minimized.
I'm looking for a way to run any program headless on Windows.
Is there anyway i can keep the GUI hidden while program is running ?

Comment: What is the application?

Comment: The program would need to support being able to do this.  If it does not you can add that functionality if its your program, if it isn't your program, there are not a great deal of choices.

Comment: Sadly, there’s no `window-management` tag, because that’s what this is about. That being said, the `headless` tag refers to something else, so I removed it.

Comment: AT Ramhound   It may well be impossible, but state why you think it's impossible. There have been numerous instances when you don't know how to do something, and you tell people it's impossible, then it turns out that there is a way to do it

Comment: The application is Firefox and it's running an automated script. I know I can use e.g. PhantomJS but I'd rather stick to Firefox.